# Get data from a website based on content in worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, web-crawler

```
        Sub try()
        Dim ie As Object
        Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
        Dim MyURL As String
        Dim MyURLSer As String
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   On Error GoTo Err_Clear
    MyURL = "[http://test.com/login][1]"
   Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    MyBrowser.Silent = True
   MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
   MyBrowser.Visible = True
        Do
      Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
HTMLDoc.all.j_username.Value = "User" 'Enter your email id here
HTMLDoc.all.j_password.Value = Password'Enter your password here
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If MyHTML_Element.Type = "button" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "http://test.com/home"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

My problem is when I try to enter the number that I want to search in the website I'm unable to do that. Unable to enter the submit button.

```html
<FORM name=menuSearchForm id=menuSearchForm style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px" action=abc/search/default method=post>
<INPUT name=searchKeyword class=search-field id=search value="Enter number" jQuery19101740035784191712="16">
<TD class=search_btn><A style="MARGIN: 0px" onclick=javascript:submitSearch(); href="javascript:void(0);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the javascript directly.

```
Call HTMLDoc.parentWindow.execScript("submitSearch();", "javascript")
```

The `href` in the `a` element is set to do nothing but the `onClick` is set to run the above script.